# How do I connect Galaxy Watch 4 to Android Studio?

Tags: android

I am working with the wear OS sample watch faces. I can get them to run on the emulator but I can't seem to connect my watch 4 to run them on the watch. From my research I think it could be an issue with "abd" and doing something in the terminal but I've been unsuccessful. Another thing I noticed and I'm not sure if it's relevant, is that when I connect my phone with USB there is a caution symbol next to it that says warning missing watch. But I'm not sure if that's relevant. Can someone assist with connecting the watch 4?

Answer (score 2):

In Watch 4 settings, turn on developer options. Then enable adb debugging. The watch must be connected to the same Wi-Fi network as your computer. Then on PC write in the console

```
adb connect [watch address ip addred from settings]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Set up a watch**

Deploying an app to a watch is similar to deploying an app to a phone.

This section assumes that your watch has a USB port. If your watch lacks a USB port, see the instructions for connecting your watch using Wi-Fi or Bluetooth.

Enable `adb` debugging on the watch:

- Open the Settings menu on the watch.
- Scroll to the bottom of the menu. If no Developer options item is provided, tap System and then About.
- Tap the build number 7 times.
- From the Settings menu, tap Developer options.
- Enable ADB debugging.

**Connect the watch:**

- Connect the watch to your machine through USB, so you can install apps directly to the watch.
- On the watch, tap Always allow from this computer and tap OK.

After you connect the watch, run your app by selecting a deployment target as described in Build and run your app.

https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/get-started/debugging